# Android: Performance 'hickups' in live wallpaper application

Tags: java, android, performance, opengl-es

I'm experiencing some problems with a live wallpaper application that i'm writing.

I'm using OpenGL 1.0 for rendering. In general the performance that i'm getting is pretty decent. On a Samsung Galaxy S2 (2.3.4) i can get 60 FPS without frame limiting.

However from time to time i get some frames that are considerably larger than others (let's say a normal frame is 33ms and a spike frame is around 70-100ms). This happens on regular intervals, roughly once every second.

My code does exactly the same processing every frame so this behavior is abnormal. It looks like that my thread is being swapped / delayed by the OS for some reason or just the VM starts executing slower at some point.

The slowdowns are not due to GPU processing as eglSwapBuffers never waits. I'm also pretty sure that my process does not cause the GC to run because i make sure not to have any short lived objects in my loop (verified in DDMS allocation tracker).

An interesting thing is that if i keep my finger on the screen the spikes in the frame time tend to get considerably smaller. As if the OS boosts the priority of the process because of this.

Solving this issue is very important because my animations look very bad when a spike occurs.

Did anyone else experience the same issue? Any hints as to what might be causing the problem would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are right. As a live wallpaper, you are not expected to be the only active thread, so whenever another application needs to do its thing, you will get delays. As far as I know, you cannot control this. On one of my applications, the worse is when I get a e-mail, where I get a half-second freeze. In your case, *regular intervals* lead me to think that another process is checking something every second or so. Sometimes you'll get hints in the logcat, with a recurring process showing up every time.

I do not have a solution for this, but what helps a bit (depending on the nature of your animations - and this is assuming you are animating using each frame as your time step, apologies if not) is to use the actual time elapsed between the last frame and the current one. Any spike will then "freeze" the display, but not the animation. It's subtle, but sometimes it might be enough.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like a long garbage collection pass to me. [EDIT] You mention you've cut down on your allocations - perhaps there's another app or library which is causing a spike?

Thread context switching will happen, but unless you're very close to the limit in terms of CPU usage (i.e. you're using 16ms of CPU power per frame) then that's not going to be your issue. You're currently almost certainly limited by the GPU frame buffer switching frequency (60 switches per second maximum.)

I would also say that live wallpapers should generally have the option to limit the update frequency to an even 15fps. Battery drain is a factor you need to seriously consider for a live wallpaper.